# Is it possible to store Ruby commands and execute their output later?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to do something a little unusual as a workaround to another problem. I would like to store ruby commands and execute them later.

I can store commands in variables ok but I can only print them to the screen, I played around with flatten to see could I somehow convert them to a usable form but it didn't work.

Here is an example:

```
Command_Store = Array[puts "Hello World", my_first_array = array.new, puts "Hello World again"]

execute.Command_Store[0] => Hello World 
execute.Command_Store[1] => my.first_array[] 
execute.Command_Store[2] => Hello World again
```

Comment: That's exactly what lambda and block are used for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Also you can use lambda for this kind of task:

```
command_store = []
command_store << lambda { puts "Hello World" }
command_store << lambda { my_first_array = Array.new }
command_store << lambda { puts "Hello World again" }

command_store.each(&:call) 
#=> Hello World
#=> Hello World again
```

UPDATE:

You can capture the variable `my_first_array`, that's what called the closure

```
my_first_array = [3,4,5,6,7]

command_store << lambda { puts my_first_array[0] }

command_store.each(&:call)
#=> ...
#=> 3
```

Comment: could I use this to output the command puts my_first_array[0] so that ruby would print the contents of my_first_array[0]

Comment: ugh sorry about this I am having issues with this for more complex querys, here is an example                                                                                                                                                 clues = Array.new

clues << 'Power supply type'
clues << 'Slots'
clues << 'Software included'    
    
Var100 = clues.rindex('Software included')
Var101 = "clues[#{Var100}]"
command_store = Array.new
command_store <<  lambda {puts "clues[#{Var101}]" }

Comment: Create new answer because of bad formatting i can't understand what is the problem.

Comment: @Ninja2k, you've changed the subject and now all the answers are not related to your question. Please, make another question.

Comment: Ok made a new answer, your answer helped perfectly with this question so I will mark it as answered.

Answer (score 5):

Why not use the standard function [eval()](http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/Eval-Running-Code-On-The-Fly.htm) ?

e.g. (from the linked article)

```
code = "Time.now"
result = eval(code)
puts result
```

Answer (score 1):

You have already some answer to use lambdas (which is the correct answer).

> I would like to store ruby commands and execute them later.

If the *later* is at the end of the script you could use `END`:

```
END {
  puts 1
}
puts 2
```

result:

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of better **variable scope** and **visibility**, I would recommend to use **blocks**.  But **lambda** is a perfect solution if you just want to store and execute.

From my understanding, I guess you would like to access my_first_array somewhere outside command_store.  So in your case it would be:

***Scenario I***: if you don't want to expose my_first_array, but still want to play with it somehow.

```
def command_store
  puts 'Hello World'
  # here my_first_array is just a local variable inside command_store
  my_first_array = Array.new(5) {|i| Random.rand(100)}
  yield(my_first_array)
  puts 'Hello World again'
end

command_store() do |x|
  # puts '**Call from outside'
  puts "The first element is #{x[0]}"
  # ...
  puts "The last element is #{x[-1]}"
  # puts '**Call from outside again'
end

# Output:
# => Hello World
# => The first element is 41
# => The last element is 76
# => Hello World again
```

***Scenario II***: suppose you want the assignment statement being valid to an external variable.  It's also a good idea to consider using binding for this case.

```
def command_store(var=[])
  puts 'Hello World'
  # here my_first_array is just a local variable inside command_store
  my_first_array = Array.new(5) {|i| Random.rand(100)}
  var.replace(my_first_array)
  puts 'Hello World again'
  return var
end

a = Array.new
command_store(a)
puts a[0]

b = command_store()
puts b[0]

# Output:
# => Hello World
# => Hello World again
# => 66
# => Hello World
# => Hello World again
# => 16
```

Comment: If you prefer more flexibility, like being able to call just `command_store()` without any block, then you can add `if block_given?` after `yield`.